# My kivy code isnt showing an image on the button

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, kivy

I wrote this to display a button with given image

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class DatesPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DatesPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_butt = Button(background_normal='plus_butt.png', size_hint=(0.2, 0.1))
        self.add_widget(self.add_butt)

class DiaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return DatesPage()

if __name__=='__main__':
    DiaryApp().run()
```

How can i make sure that the image is displayed on the button

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a window with this code. Because you are not calling DiaryApp class correctly.Add brackets after class name.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    DiaryApp().run()
```

Comment: i corrected it but still i m not getting the output @320V

Comment: Are you getting an error or only can't see button image now ? Share error if you have please. Because it works on my linux.Python 3.6.9 , kivy 1.11.1 version.